# How did Revision a to the OAuth Core 1.0 address the session fixation issue?

Tags: security, oauth, authorization

From reading the [OAuth Core 1.0 specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/), it looks like the [session fixation attack](http://oauth.net/advisories/2009-1/) was possible because OAuth 1.0 allowed the consumer **(client)** to get a request token just *before* the user **(resource owner)** authenticated himself with the service provider **(resource server / authorization server)** and authorized the request.

*Revision a* claims to have resolved the session fixation issue.

But I cannot find a concise summary of how. Further, I cannot easily understand [this summary](http://oauth.net/advisories/2009-1/). Could someone point me to the summary and also confirm if my assumption stated above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session fixation issue is not solved by change in the protocol itself.

The spec was changed to warn the implementers about the possible attack and to give them guidance on implementing measurements that prevent it. Those measurements are outside of the scope of the protocol itself. They are security considerations and guidance.

For diff of changes see:
https://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/diff?spec=svn1058&old=991&r=1058&format=unidiff&path=%2Fspec%2Fcore%2F1.0a%2Foauth-core-1_0a.xml